# Get data out of FeatureCollection

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, feature-collection

I am just trying to get the admin area out of FAO/GAUL/2015/level2 for Romania when I click in the map and use it as a label in a panel.

It works in the console but in the panel it prints out way too much. What am I doing wrong??

See code below:

```
// Create a FeatureCollection from the list and print it.
var fromList = ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL/2015/level2");

var filter = ee.Filter.inList('ADM0_NAME', ['Romania']);
var filteredArea = fromList.filter(filter);

//print(filteredArea);

Map.setCenter(25.1, 45.5, 6);
Map.addLayer(filteredArea, {}, 'Regions');

// Create a panel to hold the chart.
var panel = ui.Panel();
panel.style().set({
  width: '400px',
  position: 'bottom-right'
});
Map.add(panel);

// Register a function to draw a chart when a user clicks on the map.
Map.onClick(function(coords) {
  panel.clear();
  var label = ui.Label('This is a panel Example',{textAlign: 'center'});
  panel.add(label);
  var point = ee.Geometry.Point(coords.lon, coords.lat);
  var filteredPoint = filteredArea.filterBounds(point);
  print(filteredPoint.aggregate_first("ADM1_NAME"));
  var AreaName = filteredPoint.aggregate_first("ADM1_NAME");
  print(AreaName);
  var label = ui.Label(AreaName);
  panel.add(label);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to get the name on the client-side. [See here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/client_server) for an explanation about client and server-side objects in the GEE. An example for your code would be:

```
  var AreaName = filteredPoint.aggregate_first("ADM1_NAME").evaluate(function(evalName){
    panel.add(ui.Label(evalName));
  })
```

[link code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/c24ec5a2ce673179d5a0bd9d0011ccbc)